# How can I check if the user is still subscribed and how can I get my subscription expiration date in order to show it to the user?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Soo, below is my implementation of Flutter In-app purchases on both ios and android.

For this, I've used **flutter_inapp_purchase 5.1.2** package.

The main problem is when I try to get an active subscription on ios. What I mean is that I have no clue how to check exactly whether the user is still subscribed or not. I tested my app 2 months ago and `getAvailablePurcheses` provides me with a purchase that has `purchaseDate` set to 2 months ago.

How can I check if the user is still subscribed and how can I get my subscription expiration date in order to show it to the user?

Please help, I hope this class will be useful to other users later.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:estimator_ar/models/user.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inapp_purchase/flutter_inapp_purchase.dart';

import 'dart:io' show Platform;

class PaymentService {

  /// We want singelton object of ``PaymentService`` so create private constructor
  PaymentService._internal();
  static final PaymentService instance = PaymentService._internal();
  StreamSubscription<ConnectionResult> _connectionSubscription;
  StreamSubscription<PurchasedItem> _purchaseUpdatedSubscription;

  /// To listen the errors of the purchase
  StreamSubscription<PurchaseResult> _purchaseErrorSubscription;
  final String _productId = 'estimator_tier_1';
  IAPItem _product;
  ObserverList<Function> _subscriptionStatusChangedListeners = new ObserverList<Function>();
  ObserverList<Function(String)> _errorListeners =new ObserverList<Function(String)>();

  /// Call this method at the startup of you app to initialize connection
  /// with billing server and get all the necessary data
  Future<void> initConnection() async {
    await FlutterInappPurchase.instance.initialize();
    _connectionSubscription = FlutterInappPurchase.connectionUpdated.listen((connected) {});
    _purchaseUpdatedSubscription = FlutterInappPurchase.purchaseUpdated.listen(_handlePurchaseUpdate);
    _purchaseErrorSubscription = FlutterInappPurchase.purchaseError.listen(_handlePurchaseError);
    _getItem();
  }

  /// call when user close the app
  void dispose() {
    _connectionSubscription.cancel();
    _purchaseErrorSubscription.cancel();
    _purchaseUpdatedSubscription.cancel();
    FlutterInappPurchase.instance.finalize();
  }

  void _handlePurchaseError(PurchaseResult purchaseError) {
    this._callErrorListeners(purchaseError.message);
  }

  /// Called when new updates arrives at ``purchaseUpdated`` stream
  void _handlePurchaseUpdate(PurchasedItem productItem) async {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      await _handlePurchaseUpdateAndroid(productItem);
    } else {
      await _handlePurchaseUpdateIOS(productItem);
    }
  }

  Future<void> _handlePurchaseUpdateIOS(PurchasedItem purchasedItem) async {
    switch (purchasedItem.transactionStateIOS) {
      case TransactionState.deferred:
        break;
      case TransactionState.failed:
        print("Transaction failed");
        FlutterInappPurchase.instance.finishTransaction(purchasedItem);
        break;
      case TransactionState.purchased:
        print("Transaction finished");
        await _verifyAndFinishTransaction(purchasedItem);
        break;
      case TransactionState.purchasing:
        break;
      case TransactionState.restored:
        FlutterInappPurchase.instance.finishTransaction(purchasedItem);
        break;
      default:
    }
  }

  Future<void> _handlePurchaseUpdateAndroid(PurchasedItem purchasedItem) async {
    switch (purchasedItem.purchaseStateAndroid) {
      case PurchaseState.purchased:
        if (!purchasedItem.isAcknowledgedAndroid) {
          await _verifyAndFinishTransaction(purchasedItem);
        }
        break;
      default:
        print("Something went wrong");
    }
  }

  _verifyAndFinishTransaction(PurchasedItem purchasedItem) async {
    if(loggedUser!=null)
      loggedUser.updateSubscriptionStatus(true);
    FlutterInappPurchase.instance.finishTransaction(purchasedItem);
    _callSubscriptionStatusChangedListeners();
  }

  Future<IAPItem> get product async {
    if (_product == null)
      await _getItem();
    return _product;
  }

  Future<void> _getItem() async {
    List<IAPItem> items = await FlutterInappPurchase.instance.getSubscriptions([_productId]);
    _product = null;
    if(items.length>0)
      this._product = items[0];
  }

  Future<Null> buyProduct(IAPItem item) async {
    try {
      await FlutterInappPurchase.instance.requestPurchase(item.productId);
    } catch (error) {
    }
  }

  Future<bool> checkActiveSubscription() async{
    try{
      var _purchase = await this.getActiveSubscription();
      print(_purchase.transactionDate);
      return _purchase!=null;
    }catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
    }
    if(loggedUser!=null)
      loggedUser.updateSubscriptionStatus(false);
    return false;
  }

  Future<PurchasedItem> getActiveSubscription() async{

    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      var history = await FlutterInappPurchase.instance.getPurchaseHistory();

      for (var purchase in history)
        if([TransactionState.purchased, TransactionState.restored].contains(purchase.transactionStateIOS))
          return purchase;
      return null;
    } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      var purchases = await FlutterInappPurchase.instance.getAvailablePurchases();

      for (var purchase in purchases) {
        if (purchase.productId == _product.productId) return purchase;
      }
      return null;
    }
    throw PlatformException(code: Platform.operatingSystem, message: "platform not supported");
  }

  /// Call this method to notify all the subsctibers of _proStatusChangedListeners
  void _callSubscriptionStatusChangedListeners() {
    _subscriptionStatusChangedListeners.forEach((Function callback) {
      callback();
    });
  }

  /// Call this method to notify all the subsctibers of _errorListeners
  void _callErrorListeners(String error) {
    _errorListeners.forEach((Function callback) {
      callback(error);
    });
  }

  /// view can subscribe to _proStatusChangedListeners using this method
  addToSubscriptionStatusChangedListeners(Function callback) {
    _subscriptionStatusChangedListeners.add(callback);
  }
  /// view can cancel to _proStatusChangedListeners using this method
  removeFromSubscriptionStatusChangedListeners(Function callback) {
    _subscriptionStatusChangedListeners.remove(callback);
  }

  /// view can subscribe to _errorListeners using this method
  addToErrorListeners(Function callback) {
    _errorListeners.add(callback);
  }
  /// view can cancel to _errorListeners using this method
  removeFromErrorListeners(Function callback) {
    _errorListeners.remove(callback);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code instead.

```
// ignore_for_file: avoid_print

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:ai_image_generator/common/snackbar.dart';
import 'package:ai_image_generator/helper/navigation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inapp_purchase/flutter_inapp_purchase.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

bool get isPro => SubscriptionController.find.isPro;

class SubscriptionController extends GetxController implements GetxService {
  static SubscriptionController get find => Get.find<SubscriptionController>();

  final FlutterInappPurchase _iap = FlutterInappPurchase.instance;

  final List<String> _subscriptionIds = const <String>[
    'yearly_plan',
    'monthly_plan',
    'weekly_plan',
  ];
  List<IAPItem> _products = [];
  late StreamSubscription _purchaseUpdatedSubscription;
  DateTime? _proLimitDate;

  List<IAPItem> get products => _products;
  DateTime? get proLimitDate => _proLimitDate;

  set products(List<IAPItem> value) {
    _products = value;
    update();
  }

  set proLimitDate(DateTime? value) {
    _proLimitDate = value;
    update();
  }

  Future<void> init() async {
    await _iap.initialize();
    await _getSubscriptiions();
    await refreshProStatus();
    _purchaseUpdatedSubscription =
        FlutterInappPurchase.purchaseUpdated.listen((result) {
      _verifyPurchase(result, callback: () {
        pop();
        showToast('purchase_success'.tr, success: true);
      });
    });
  }

  Future<void> _getSubscriptiions() async {
    var data = await _iap.getSubscriptions(_subscriptionIds);
    if (data.isNotEmpty) {
      _products.addAll(data);
    }
    update();
  }

  Future<void> buyProduct(IAPItem productDetails,
      {Function()? callback}) async {
    try {
      await _iap.requestSubscription(productDetails.productId!);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  _verifyPurchase(PurchasedItem? result, {Function()? callback}) async {
    if (result == null) {
      // Handle the case where the purchase is null
      return;
    }
    // Check if the purchase is successful
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      if (result.purchaseStateAndroid == PurchaseState.purchased) {
        _finishTransaction(result, callback: callback);
      }
    } else {
      if (result.transactionStateIOS == TransactionState.purchased ||
          result.transactionStateIOS == TransactionState.restored) {
        _finishTransaction(result, callback: callback);
      }
    }
  }

  Future<void> _finishTransaction(PurchasedItem result,
      {Function()? callback}) async {
    DateTime? purchaseTime = result.transactionDate;

    switch (result.productId!.toLowerCase()) {
      case "yearly_plan":
        purchaseTime = purchaseTime?.add(const Duration(days: 365));
        break;
      case "monthly_plan":
        purchaseTime = purchaseTime?.add(const Duration(days: 30));
        break;
      case "weekly_plan":
        purchaseTime = purchaseTime?.add(const Duration(days: 7));
        break;

      default:
        return;
    }
    if (DateTime.now().isBefore(purchaseTime!)) {
      proLimitDate = purchaseTime;
    }
    try {
      await _iap.finishTransaction(result);
      if (callback != null) callback.call();
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
  }

  Future refreshProStatus() async {
    // get past purchases
    var result = await _iap.getAvailablePurchases();
    if (result != null && result.isNotEmpty) {
      for (var item in result) {
        _verifyPurchase(item);
      }
    }
  }

  bool get isPro {
    if (proLimitDate == null) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return DateTime.now().isBefore(proLimitDate!);
    }
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    _purchaseUpdatedSubscription.cancel();
    super.onClose();
  }
}
```